# factory object and case class

Tags: scala, factory, case-class

I want to create factory object with apply method defined that would create underlying case class - here is a sample code

```
object DeptEntry {  
  def apply(url: String, fullName: String, address: String, city: String): DeptEntry = {
    new DeptEntry(url.toLowerCase, fullName.toLowerCase, address.toLowerCase, city.toLowerCase)
  }
}

case class DeptEntry private(url: String, fullName: String, address: String, city: String) {
}
```

The problem is that apply method in the object and case class's constructor have the same parameter list.
So compiler gives me this error:

```
method apply is defined twice
  conflicting symbols both originated in file 'DeptEntry.scala'
case class DeptEntry private(url: String, fullName: String,
       ^
```

Is there some workaround for this problem?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility would be to hide (a bit) the class from your users:

```
sealed trait DeptEntry
object DeptEntry {
  def apply(url: String, fullName: String,
            address: String, city: String): DeptEntry = // ...

  case class Value protected[DeptEntry](
    url: String, fullName: String, address: String, city: String
  )
}
```

This way there is no conflict and you still can pattern match on `DeptEntry.Value` if you need. It depends on your use case if this solution is convenient or not. If you want that the trait has the proper `val`s, you can declare it as

```
sealed trait DeptEntry {
    val url: String
    val fullName: String
    val address: String
    val city: String
}
```

and the fields in the `case class` will override them.

Comment: thanks - your solution gave me an compilation error - "Value constructor could not be accessed from DeptEntry" -> I changed private to protected[DeptEntry] and it is OK now

Comment: @user2549756 Sorry, I didn't have time to try compiling it. I'll correct the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Declare the case class `abstract`

```
object DeptEntry {  
  def apply(url: String, fullName: String, address: String, city: String): DeptEntry = {
    new DeptEntry(url.toLowerCase, fullName.toLowerCase, address.toLowerCase, city.toLowerCase) {}
  }
}

abstract case class DeptEntry private(url: String, fullName: String, address: String, city: String) {
}
```

This is according to Iulian Dragos [commenting on SI-844](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-844?focusedCommentId=41556&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-41556)

Answer (score 1):

When you create a `case class`, the Scala compiler automatically generates a companion object with an apply method for you. This apply method has the same parameters as the case class's constructor. This is why you get this compiler error. The fact that you can't overwrite it ensures that stuff like that holds:

```
val inputUrl = "MyUrl://blabla"
val DeptEntry(outputUrl, _, _, _) = DeptEntry(inputUrl, "", "", "")
outputUrl == inputUrl
```

Try removing the `case` from the class definition and write the companion object's `apply` (and `unapply` if you need extraction) yourself (and `toString`, `equals` and `hashCode` in the class itself if needed).

Comment: pls see my comment on Fabian's answer

Comment: Well it's simple: either you use a `case class` and you accept the compiler's constraints (one of which is the one explained here), or you don't use a `case class`.

Comment: If you define a non-case class, you can extends `Product` and then do stuff like `override def hashCode = ScalaRunTime._hashCode(this)`. But implementing `Product` is probably not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You could make DeptEntry a "normal" (not case class) class. Or you can use a Method with a different name in the Object. (e.g. DeptEntry.lowerCase(...))

Comment: it needs to be a case class because of auto-generated equals/hashcode methods that I need